Flutter app changes the route without instructions
I have a very unusual problem in Flutter.
I'm trying to read a barcode from a product and then use it to query the product in an API.
Both parts that I have written for this work independently of each other smoothly and reliably. However, when I try to put them together a strange behaviour appears.
I have put the barcode scanner into an alert dialogue. When it recognizes the barcode, it returns it to the previous route. In this dialogue the code is then taken and delivered to the API.
If I have the code output at this point, it also works perfectly.
However, as soon as I add the API, it happens that the flutter app goes back one page further when it exits the popup. This happens without any error messages or similar. Can anyone tell me why this happens?
This error only happens when I use the following Scan class. if I use an alternative, then this happens without error
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:mobile_scanner/mobile_scanner.dart';
import 'package:qr_scanner_overlay/qr_scanner_overlay.dart';

Future<String?> showQrScannerDialog({required BuildContext context}) async {
  return showDialog<String>(
    context: context,
    barrierDismissible: false,
    builder: (BuildContext context) {
      return QrScannerDialog();
    },
  );
}

class QrScannerDialog extends StatefulWidget{
  const QrScannerDialog({super.key});

  @override
  _QrScannerDialogState createState() => _QrScannerDialogState();
}

class _QrScannerDialogState extends State<QrScannerDialog> with WidgetsBindingObserver {

  MobileScannerController controller = MobileScannerController();
  StreamSubscription<Object?>? _subscription;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    // Start listening to lifecycle changes.
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addObserver(this as WidgetsBindingObserver);

    // Start listening to the barcode events.
    _subscription = controller.barcodes.listen(_handleBarcode);

    // Finally, start the scanner itself.
    unawaited(controller.start());
  }

  @override
  void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) {
    // If the controller is not ready, do not try to start or stop it.
    // Permission dialogs can trigger lifecycle changes before the controller is ready.
    if (!controller.value.isInitialized) {
      return;
    }

    switch (state) {
      case AppLifecycleState.detached:
      case AppLifecycleState.hidden:
      case AppLifecycleState.paused:
        return;
      case AppLifecycleState.resumed:
      // Restart the scanner when the app is resumed.
      // Don't forget to resume listening to the barcode events.
        _subscription = controller.barcodes.listen(_handleBarcode);

        unawaited(controller.start());
      case AppLifecycleState.inactive:
      // Stop the scanner when the app is paused.
      // Also stop the barcode events subscription.
        unawaited(_subscription?.cancel());
        _subscription = null;
        unawaited(controller.stop());
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AlertDialog(
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
          side: BorderSide(
              color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary, width: 2),
        ),
        title: Text("QR Scanner"),
        content: AspectRatio(
          aspectRatio: 1,
          child: Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              border: Border.all(
                color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary,
                width: 2,
              ),
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
            ),
            child: Center(
              child: Stack(
                children: [
                  MobileScanner(
                    controller: controller,
                    // onDetect: (code) {
                    //   if(code.barcodes.isEmpty) return;
                    //   if(code.barcodes.first.rawValue == null) return;
                    //   String barcode = code.barcodes.first.rawValue!;
                    //   Navigator.of(context).pop(barcode);
                    // },
                  ),
                  QRScannerOverlay(
                    borderColor: Colors.red,
                    borderRadius: 16,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        actions: <Widget>[
          TextButton(
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.of(context).pop();
            },
            child: Text('Abbrechen'),
          ),
        ]);
  }

  @override
  Future<void> dispose() async {
    // Stop listening to lifecycle changes.
    WidgetsBinding.instance.removeObserver(this);
    // Stop listening to the barcode events.
    unawaited(_subscription?.cancel());
    _subscription = null;
    // Dispose the widget itself.
    super.dispose();
    // Finally, dispose of the controller.
    await controller.dispose();
  }

  void _handleBarcode(Object? barcode) {
    if (barcode == null) return;
    if (barcode is BarcodeCapture) {
      BarcodeCapture capture = barcode;
      if(capture.barcodes.isEmpty) return;
      Navigator.of(context).pop(capture.barcodes.first.rawValue);
    }
  }
}

My Code:
the Function, which grabs the information from the API
Future<Product?> searchByBarcode(String barcode) async{
    final ProductQueryConfiguration configuration = ProductQueryConfiguration(
      barcode,
      language: OpenFoodFactsLanguage.GERMAN,
      fields: [ProductField.ALL],
      version: ProductQueryVersion.v3,
    );

    OpenFoodAPIConfiguration.userAgent = UserAgent(
      name: '',
      version: '',
      system: 'Android',
    );

//TODO: user für unsere App Erstellen und in Secrets klasse auslagern
    User user = const User(
      userId: 'username',
      password: 'password',);

    final ProductResultV3 result = await OpenFoodAPIClient.getProductV3(
        configuration, user: user);

    if (result.status == ProductResultV3.statusSuccess) {
      var prod = result.product;
      return prod;
    } else {
      throw Exception('product not found, please insert data for $barcode');
    }
  }

The method that handles the whole process
 Future<void> addObjectByBarcode(BuildContext context) async {
    String? barcode = await showQrScannerDialog(context: context);
    print(barcode); //<--- works fine
    if(barcode != null){
      OpenFoodFactsApi api = OpenFoodFactsApi();
      try {
        Product? product = await api.searchByBarcode(barcode);
        if (product != null) {
          print(product.productName); //<- prints teh actual Product name
        }
      } catch (e, s) {
        print(e);
        print(s);
        CustomSnackBar.show(context, 'Fehler beim Abrufen des Produkts: $e');
      }
    } else {
      CustomSnackBar.show(context, 'Barcode konnte nicht richtig gescannt werden.');
    }
  }

